# Save and load lists of strings in Python using JSON

Tags: python, json, list

I am trying to save lists (one per line) in a file like

```
            w = meaningful_words
            json.dump(w, outfile)
            outfile.write("\n");
```

where w is a list of strings. Then I'm trying to load the lists, one at a time like

```
with open('text.txt', 'r') as file:
    for line in file:
        data = json.loads(line.read())
```

But I get the error

```
data = json.loads(line.read())
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'read'
```

Is there another way to do this? Found out JSON wood be easy to use but I can't get it to work.

Comment: use dumps not loads

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should change `line.read()` to just `line`:

```
with open('text.txt', 'r') as infile:
    for line in infile:
        data = json.loads(line)
```

[File objects](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#bltin-file-objects) are iterators returning the next line if [`file.next()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#file.next) is called. The returned value is already a string and that's why you get the error message `AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'read'`

Comment: Thank you! Can you tell me why?

Comment: @Knokkelgeddon just edited my answer to include some explanation.